# Python: pdoc doesn't launch browser

Tags: python, batch-file, webserver

I have a Windows batch file that says:

`"C:\Users\<myname>\Anaconda3\Scripts\pdoc3.exe" <mymodule>`

In the past, this launched the `pdoc` web server and a browser window. However, I just switched Python distributions (now using pdoc 0.9.2 on Anaconda). Now, this same batch file (just with the executable path updated) dumps part of my documentation to the console and returns without launching a web server. However, my other batch file:

`"C:\Users\<myname>\Anaconda3\Scripts\pdoc3.exe" -o ./docs <mymodule>`

works fine.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is kinda dumb, but I had installed `pdoc3` instead of `pdoc` by mistake. Removing `pdoc3` and installing `pdoc` solved the problem.

(I had to use `pip` instead of `conda`. The provided install string `conda install -c auto pdoc` didn't work.)